# transparent wrapper for python atoms

Tags: python, oop, object

I want to extend the behavior of some atomic values in python via wrapper object s.t. it will unwrap itself when the wrapper doesn't know what to do.
The wrapper should be agnostic about it's atom, so anything could fit inside.

let's say the following tests should pass:

```
    def test_wrapper_object_adds_functionality_on_top_of_int():
        wrapper = MagicWrap(2)
        assert wrapper+2 == 4
        assert wrapper*2 == 4
        assert wrapper**2 == 4
        assert wrapper.foo() == "bar"

    def test_wrapper_object_adds_functionality_on_top_of_str():
        wrapper = MagicWrap("foo")
        assert wrapper+"2" == "foo2"
        assert wrapper*2 == "foofoo"
        assert wrapper.foo() == "bar"
```

The above tests do not check commutativity, so this is level 2:

```
    def test_wrapper_is_commutative_as_int():
        wrapper = MagicWrap(2)
        assert 2+wrapper == 4
        assert 2*wrapper == 4
        assert 2**wrapper == 4
        assert wrapper.foo() == "bar"

    def test_wrapper_is_commutative_as_str():
        wrapper = MagicWrap("foo")
        assert "2"+wrapper == "2foo"
        assert 2*wrapper == "foofoo"
        assert wrapper.foo() == "bar"
```

An answer that just satisfies level 1 would still be interesting.

I use python 3 specifically.

Comment: so far I tried iterating over the dict of the inserted type, and adding it's attributes to the wrapper. Then when I use addition I get a TypeError. I tried adding the attribute to the __class__ of the wrapper, but if I add the atom's attribute there it creates a singe definition for all instances (MagicWrap(2)+2 == MagicWrap(4)+2) which is not good. However if I plant the attribute of the __class__ of atom, it reverts to being a TypeError.

Comment: So turns out that level 2 is impossible to pull off without reflecting the atomic classes involved. The problem being that types are verified at the body of the addition function, so If the wrapped type comes first, my unwrapping function will be called. otherwise, the atom's function will be invoked and throw an exception.